# Determine whether the active check box is checked in Winforms

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, checkbox, focus

I am developing a Windows Forms Application using Visual Studio in Visual C++.  My form has 96 check boxes on it.  Rather than create 96 Click events, I believe that there's a way to create a single Click event that is called when any check box is clicked.  Within the Click event, I need to determine whether the active checkbox is Checked or Not Checked.  While this should be easy, I can't seem to figure it out!

I got it to work with the code below, but I'm sure there's a better way.

```
    if (sender == checkBox_D1)
    {
        if (checkBox_D1->Checked)
            isChecked = true;
    }
    else if (sender == checkBox_D2)
    {
        if (checkBox_D2->Checked)
            isChecked = true;
    }
    else
        return; // Invalid sender - should not get here!

    if (isChecked)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else
    }
```

I also tried the code below but activeCheckBox is not a Checkbox object so it doesn't work.

Control^ activeCheckBox = ActiveControl;

activeCheckBox->Text returns the Text property of the Checkbox

activeCheckBox->Checked doesn't compile.  The error is 'Checked' : is not a member of 'System::Windows::Forms::Control'

It seems like sender has the data that I need but I don't know how to access it.

Is there a way to declare a Checkbox as follows?

CheckBox activeBox;

and then assign activeBox to the Checkbox that has the focus
activeBox = ???

```
// Then just need to do this!
if (activeBox.Checked)
    isChecked = true;
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can reuse the same function for all your Check boxes.

```
void App3::ItemPage::checkBox_Checked(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    CheckBox^ activeCheckBox = safe_cast<CheckBox^>(sender);

    if (activeCheckBox->Checked)
    {
        if (activeCheckBox->Name == "checkBox_D1") {
            //Do something when this check box is clicked.
        }
        if (activeCheckBox->Name == "checkBox_D2") {
            //Do something when this check box is clicked.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi EJD, Thank you for looking at my question and for your reply.  I get an error when I compile CheckBox activeCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender; In your example, sender is passed as type object.  I am using Winforms and sender is passed as a System::Object^.  The errors are C2440 and C3673.  Thanks!

Comment: What's the error ?  I didn't notice you were using visual -++ the idea is still the same you need to cast sender to a CheckBox.

Comment: I get two errors: C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox'
1>          Conversion requires a constructor or user-defined-conversion operator, which can't be used by const_cast or reinterpret_cast
error C3673: 'System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox' : class does not have a copy-constructor

Comment: Modified the code to Visual C++ let me know how I did my first code :)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!  You have now graduated to C++ lol  I only had to make one minor change to your code.  if (activeCheckBox->Checked) ...  IsChecked is Visual Basic  The key was the proper way to cast sender to a Checkbox.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For all checBoxes you will assign the same CheckedChanged event:

```
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += newCheckBoxCheckedOrUnchecked_CheckedChanged;
checkBox2.CheckedChanged += newCheckBoxCheckedOrUnchecked_CheckedChanged;
//...
//...
checkBox95.CheckedChanged += newCheckBoxCheckedOrUnchecked_CheckedChanged;
checkBox96.CheckedChanged += newCheckBoxCheckedOrUnchecked_CheckedChanged;
```

Checks the state of all checkBoxes:

```
private void newCheckBoxCheckedOrUnchecked_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
        {
            var checkBox = (CheckBox) control;
            var checkBoxName = checkBox.Name; // To know which checkbox we are talking about
            var checkBoxIsChecked = checkBox.Checked;
            // Do your stuff
            MessageBox.Show(checkBoxName + @" is " + (checkBoxIsChecked ? "checked" : "not checked"));
        }
    }
}
```

Checks the state of only the checkBox where the value was changed:

```
private void newCheckBoxCheckedOrUnchecked_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox2 = (CheckBox)sender;
    var checkBoxName2 = checkBox2.Name; // To know which checkbox we are talking about
    var checkBoxIsChecked2 = checkBox2.Checked;
    // Do your stuff
    MessageBox.Show(checkBoxName2 + @" is " + (checkBoxIsChecked2 ? "checked" : "not checked"));
}
```

Comment: Hi Isabella,  Thank you for your suggestion.  It looks like Visual Basic?  I am using C++.  That isn't the main problem.  I just don't understand your code. :o) I am going to try to figure it out, however I think that I will run into the same issue as with EJD's suggestion because you cast control to type CheckBox in your example and the compiler doesn't like this cast.  Thanks so much.

Comment: My code works but it's a very long function because it has 96 if/else if statements.  I could condense the function to a few lines if I only knew how to access the Checkbox->Checked property in System::Object^ sender.  Is this possible?  If not, I will go with my existing code.  Thanks very much.